# Facing issue in Woocommerce 3.3 version in wordpress

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently, I am facing issue in Woocommerce. I tried to place an order but am getting 500 error. I checked the error log it shows like the error below,

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_order_number() on boolean
```

I checked `woocommerce_order_items` table order item table the order_id is 0 and in backend order grid is empty. If anyone has idea means please tell me to resolve this issue.

Comment: the last stable WooCommerce version is 3.2.6. do you use a developpement version ?

Comment: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce this version only am using 3.3.0

Comment: to use the last stable version, go to the page "plugins" in the back office, deactivate and delete the plugin. After click on "add new" and install the plugin on this page.